# Is there a way to change the path of multiple references in css/html at the same time? Problem with deployment due to no index.html in root

Tags: html, css, firebase, visual-studio-code, deployment

My website files structure is as follows: a folder for pictures, and a folder containing all my html/css files.

Now that I am trying to deploy my website for the first time (I'm using FireBase), it seems that I need an index.html in my public folder's root.

However, all my html/css files are in a folder, and my pictures in another. In order to pull out my home page and rename it to index.html, I would have to change the path & name of all the files that reference it as well (which is every file). Is there any way I can avoid this?

Thanks.

(My IDE is VSCode)

Answer (score 1):

All content needs to be under a single folder, which is the one you then indicate in the [`public` option](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#public) in the `firebase.json` configuration file.

It is totally fine to have the HTML/CSS in one subfolder under there, and the images in another subfolder. But the entire `public` folder will be deployed, so you'll want to make sure you have no other files in there.

---

So this is fine:

```
public
  html_and_css
    index.html
    main.css
  images
    image1.jpg
    image2.jpg
    image3.jpg
```

---

But here you can't just deploy all of `src`, as that would also deploy the `code` subfolder that contains secrete:

```
src
  code
    secrets_that_should_not_be_published
  public
    index.html
    main.css
  images
    image1.jpg
    image2.jpg
    image3.jpg
```

If you have this last structure, you can tell Firebase to not deploy the `code` directory by specifying it in the [`ignore` option](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#ignore) in the `firebase.json` configuration file.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. However, when I test the webpage, it's the 404 page that shows up. I imagine this is because I don't have an index.html file. Is there a way to set what the index.html file is and where it's located for firebase to detect? Because otherwise I would have to go change the name of my homepage, and subsequently all the other files that reference it.

Comment: The `index.html` of a web site needs to exist in the root of that web site. If it's not there for you, you could [use a rewrite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites) or a redirect.

Comment: Hey @HelloWorld. Did you get a chance to try this?

Comment: Hey, no sorry, I simply used Find and Replace feature of vscode to replace all instances of my homepage name to index.html and renamed my file to index.html. It was easier than I imagined. But thanks anyway